# Reflection + Entity Framework to update data in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflection

I've got a complex form on a page that is bound to a POCO representing a rather complex entity. One of the requirements is that, on blur, I update the database.

I'm currently passing the property (as key), value, and CampaignId via ajax. The key might look something like: `Campaign.FanSettings.SocialSharing.FacebookLinkText`.

I am using the code below, and getting "close". My final propertyToSet is the FacebookLinkText is not being set, because my `object source` is of type Entities.Campaign, while my `object value` is simply a string. I understand these need to be the same type, but I don't understand how to do that. Two questions:

1. How do I modify the code below to be able to execute the propertyToSet.SetValue method
2. Since I'm casting this to an object, I don't see how this would actually update my entity, so when I call SaveChanges it updates appropriately. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Code:

```
    public void UpdateCampaign(int id, string key, string value)
    {
        using (var context = new BetaEntities())
        {
            var camp = context.Campaigns.Where(e => e.Id == id).Single();
            SetProperty(camp, key,value);
        }
    }
    public void SetProperty(object source, string property, object value)
    {
        string[] bits = property.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(bits[i]);
            source = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        }
        PropertyInfo propertyToSet = null;
        if (source is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (object o in (source as IEnumerable))
            {
                 propertyToSet = o.GetType().GetProperty(bits[bits.Length - 1]);
                 break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            propertyToSet = source.GetType().GetProperty(bits[bits.Length - 1]);
        }
        propertyToSet.SetValue(source, value, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
public void UpdateCampaign(int id, string key, string value)
    {
        using (var context = new BetaEntities())
        {
            var camp = context.Campaigns.Where(e => e.Id == id).Single();
            SetProperty(camp, key, value);
            context.SaveChanges()
        }
    }
    public void SetProperty(object source, string property, object value)
    {
        string[] bits = property.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(bits[i]);
            source = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        }
        PropertyInfo propertyToSet = null;
        if (source is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (object o in (source as IEnumerable))
            {
                 propertyToSet = o.GetType().GetProperty(bits[bits.Length - 1]);
                 propertyToSet.SetValue(o, value,null);
                 break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            propertyToSet = source.GetType().GetProperty(bits[bits.Length - 1]);
            propertyToSet.SetValue(source, value, null);
        }
    }
```